# How do I count specific data from a csv file and print that number in python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

For example, If i wanted to count the number of males in the 'sex' column and print that number in python. How would I do that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the countif() function will do that countif(range,"M")...

Comment: Please vote for an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

pf = open("yourcsv.csv", "r")

read = csv.reader(pf)

male_count = 0
for r in read:
    if r[1] == 'Male':
        male_count += 1
pf.close()

print("Male count: {}".format(male_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `my_csv.csv`

```
id,name,sex
1,aaa,m
2,bbb,m
3,bbb,f
4,bbb,f
5,bbb,m
6,bbb,m
```

You can count the number of males with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
print(df['sex'].value_counts()['m']) # prints 4
```